# Join productname on external table Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

May be this question was already asked..But I didn't like the answers.
I wanna to join the product Name starting from my custom resource collection.
My custom resource collection has a field called product_id. 
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

First join product entity collection to your custom collection (by product_id I suppose) then, join product name with it, like this:

$collection is your custom collection object eg: $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('custom/model_collection');

```
$prodNameAttrId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
->loadByCode('4', 'name')
->getAttributeId();

$collection->getSelect()
->joinLeft(
    array('prod' => 'catalog_product_entity'), 
    'prod.entity_id = main_table.product_id',
    array('sku')
)
->joinLeft(
    array('cpev' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'), 
    'cpev.entity_id = prod.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id='.$prodNameAttrId.'', 
    array('name' => 'value')
);
```

writing this out of head, but this should at least get you started. Wish you luck!